# error handling in observable or in observer?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, rxjs, observable

I have this method (Angular 9, so **Typescript**) which is used to retrieve a brend new Json Web Token for authenticate the current user

```
getNewAccessToken(){
    return this.httpClient.post<Token>(`${this.baseService.baseUrl}auth-token-refresh/`, { refresh: this.getRefreshToken() }, this.baseService.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((response:Token) => {
        this.cookieService.set(environment.tokenAccessName, response.access, null, '/', null, null, 'Strict');
        this.isLoggedIn.next(true);
      }
  }
```

When I subscribe to this method, I check for errors like so

```
this.authService.getNewAccessToken().subscribe(
    res => { //do something with res... },
    error => throw error    //catch error
);
```

Could I move the error detection directly inside my *observable* code using **pipe** and **catchError**? The code would turn to this

```
getNewAccessToken(){
    return this.httpClient.post<Token>(`${this.baseService.baseUrl}auth-token-refresh/`, { refresh: this.getRefreshToken() }, this.baseService.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((response:Token) => {
        this.cookieService.set(environment.tokenAccessName, response.access, null, '/', null, null, 'Strict');
        this.isLoggedIn.next(true);
      },
      catchError(error => {
        throw error;
      })
    ));
  }
```

I think this is a sort of *centralized* way of managing errors in observable. 
Generally, is error handling better on *observables* or on their *observers*?
What are the pros and cons of these two approaches? Is there any difference in terms of performance?
I think the same question can be raised for **promises**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, and it is the good practice to move error handling into `pipe` as it is separation of concern. It separates data retrieving from the presentation of the data.

[An example of code of Angular 2 documentation:](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)

```
return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. But of course, in case I had different behavours for different error types, then I 'd have to handle them separately in each **subscribe** call, hadn't I? Furthermore, your answer applies to *promises* as well?

Comment: @dc_Bita98 no, `this.handleError` should be one place where all errors should be handled. Sure, it can be applied to *promises*